# Trouble implementing p:linkButton

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to use the Primefaces link button component. I tried using Primefaces 6.2 and the project builds but I get the error message

```
"/index.xhtml @82,60 <p:linkButton> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: linkButton"
```

When I try to update my primefaces version to 6.2.RC1 or 6.2.RC2, I get a DependencyResolutionException. How can I properly link Primefaces in my pom file so that I can use the linkButton? I noticed that the Primefaces showcase for the component says it is using 6.3 and have tried that as well, even though I didn't see that version on the repository list. Is this component not available yet?

Here are the primefaces dependencies in my pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This component is supported in 7.0. At the time of the question, the showcase was running a SNAPSHOT version of 6.3 which was not released but became 7.0. sThe fact that the showcase was running something newer than OP used made it visible there. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3613

Comment: Note for future readers: There is no 6.3 as of July 2019. However this component is included in 7.0.

Answer (score -1):

Could not figure out how to get the p:linkButton working but I instead used p:button to get the same exact functionality as described in the [Primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/button.xhtml).